# screen shot function as Yahoo Chat and save it to database

Tags: vb.net, screenshot

how do i make a screen shot function as Yahoo Chat version 11.5?

i need capture a screen region and save it to database for display when user need.

And i want to a function, that accept user to pick a region on they screchuyeenrmove and hold MOUSE, then save it to Database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably "capture" the mouse let the user choose point 1 then point 2. Then pass that values to the method.